# Change Password Test Cases Selenium - Debug

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, testng, forgot-password

Below is the test that i wrote for changing password.

@Test

```
    public void changePassword() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Login();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[3]/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='change-password']/div[1]/div/input")).sendKeys("abcd");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Users_password']")).sendKeys("xyz123456");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='repassword']")).sendKeys("xyz123456");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='change-password']/div[4]/div/input")).click();
    }
}
```

Below is the Error that I am getting, I have checked the Xpath is correct, Still getting this error -

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='change-password']/div[1]/div/input"}
Command duration or timeout: 2.81 seconds
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:410)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:509)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:402)
    at pages.ChangePass.changePassword(ChangePass.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='change-password']/div[1]/div/input"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-1AKPPH7', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Users/Avinash/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous9034314523683234934webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:11390)
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement(file:///C:/Users/Avinash/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous9034314523683234934webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:11399)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/k(file:///C:/Users/Avinash/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous9034314523683234934webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12879)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/Avinash/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous9034314523683234934webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12884)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/Avinash/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous9034314523683234934webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12826)
```

My questions are -
1. What is wrong in above code, When i execute this it takes me to the change password screen.
2. Is above way the best way to test change password functionality?
3. Are there any more test scenarios that you can recomend me to include and how?

Comment: why this question is down voted ? Please specify the reason for it, so the OP can improve the question.Thanks

Comment: Would help for sure and then I can correct it, thanks Rahal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the Answers to your Question:

1. `What is wrong in above code`:

The `xpaths` you have constructed, e.g. `.//*[@id='wrapper']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[3]/a`, `.//*[@id='wrapper']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[3]/ul/li[3]/a` and `.//*[@id='change-password']/div[1]/div/input` are absolute `xpaths` which contains `index`. Hence they are **`brittle`** and **`vulnerable`**. You can consider constructing unique **`logical xpath`**.

2. `Is above way the best way to test change password functionality?`:

I don't think there are best practices in this. Because it is really depended on what you are trying to solve. But definitely before using `sendKeys("abcd")` method for a text field, you should consider using `clear()` method first.

3. When there is a `NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element`, we should consider inducing `ExplicitWait` with proper `ExpectedConditions` so **`Selenium`** can locate the element atleast.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanks you so much, I used explicit wait and the issue was solved.  I use the xpaths generated by firepath, Do you reckon i should create my own xpaths ? What do you suggest the best locators to use and any best practices to follow. Also, whats absolute vs Logical xpath. I know i have asked a lot but it would be good to know form someone who has had a lot of experience doing it.  Also, I am trying to test the functionality of change password field, so out of many test cases which would you suggest should be ideal for automation. We are moving towords automation from old set of cases

Comment: @AvinashPandey Glad to be able to help you :) Consider the `absolute xpath` generated by `firepath` as a reference to create your own unique `logical xpath`. Best locators chronologically: `id`, `name`, `linkText`, `css`, `xpath`. Can you consider to **_`Accept`_** the **_`Answer`_** as a solution to your **_`Question`_** by clicking on the tick mark beside my Answer, just below vote Up/Down arrows, so the tick mark turns Green ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First try to add HTML snippet , so the locators can be written in much more redundant way.

2nd , Use some wait mechanism for the page to be loaded properly. In your case You are clicking on a link and trying to enter data in change password input filed, the exception you are getting due to the reason the page is not loaded properly and Selenium trying to enter the value in change password filed.

For a simple solution you can use Implicit wait and it will work

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: It solved the problem thanks so much. Also, I was using it at a global level, thaught it would work, seems it does not. Also, can you suggest any more scenarios and validate if what i am using is the best way or can there be a better implementation. Please suggest. Thanks again for all help. Very much appreciated.

Comment: This is also a solution.Bu not the best. since you are hard coding the waiting time.Think of a scenario where the server get more time than 5 seconds to load.

Comment: @Rahal Kanishka This is Implicit Wait where it will wait for maximum 5 seconds, In the general Product line scenario we provide it to 30 seconds or 60 seconds, where it will wait for maximum to the provided time. For considering his scenario I asked him to use 5 seconds. Moreover It is not Hard coded like Thread.sleep().

Comment: @Arun As I know Thread.sleep() and implicit wait is not recommended that much ,recommended way is to use explicit wait. 
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));

Comment: Yes That's True, but for a beginner Implicit wait is advisable.

Comment: Agreed.  I also did on that way first and then moved to Explicit wait.